# Rhino Mocks for ASMX Web services

Tags: web-services, asmx, rhino-mocks

How do you mock old web services (not WCF) with Rhino Mocks, I can find plenty on WCf but not the old ones?

Comment: Do you mean asmx pages?  And are you talking about doing mocking inside the asmx page or doing some kind of mock for consumers of those asmx pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mock a Web Service, you have to extract an interface from the generated web service code (reference.cs), and make the web service code inherit from that interface.  You could make the web service "reference.cs" implement the interface, but may kill that code when you "update web reference".  The trick is to add a second "partial class" that will inherit from that interface.

Then you mock the interface, Gah, why didn't i think of this earlier